# .Net WebBrowser architecture

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, webbrowser-control

I'm using .Net webBrowser for html parsing

in my program i have one MainForm (form object) and the program class that initializing the MainForm.

in the form i have the webBrowser initialization and when i entering to the web site i need to handle different page's (get data from it/download files and more)

today i have all that cases in the form itself separated by regions as functions :

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   if(DoTypeA())
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
   #region TYPEA
   private bool DoTypeA()
   {
      HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document ....
      ...
   }
   #endregion TYPEA
   ...
}
```

in type A i have redirection to the page and lot of data parsing from it

can i separate that functionality in different class ? for making the code cleaner.

The problem is that the `webBrowser` and all it's events happening in the form class.

What could be the best Design patter / Architecture pattern for that case.

**What i Tried:**

- make `webBrowser` object as public.
- Make prop in `MainForm` for getting the `webBrowser` instance.

The only solution that i see is too pass the webBrowser as parameter for `DoTypeA(webBrowser);` but can i do it without passing the parameter ?

Thank's.

Comment: How about using a non-visual component for HTML parsing? Like the modern [AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp) or the popular [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or the [SGML Reader](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader).

Comment: That's one option but i have already use .Net webBrowser for my app and it's working for now i wondering how can i make it SRP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of soulution i thought about, is the DI pattern

```
class Types
{
   IWebDriver webBrowser = null;

   public Types(IWebDriver wb)
   {
      if(wb == null)
         throw new NullReferenceException();

      this.webBrowser = wb;
   }

   public bool DoTypeA()
   {
       HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document //working fine
   }
}
```

The call from MainForm

```
Types dt = new Types(webBrowser);
if(dt.GetTypeA())
{
   //done.
}
```